# Where to find the complete SGS I-9000 froyo source code?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-wifi

*(This question is indirectly related to a programming issue I'm having; if you think this question is off-topic, let me know, I remove it. Thanks).*

I try to activate WifiAP from within my app via reflection, as somewhere stated in this forum. It works on several devices, like Nexus One 2.2.1, HTC Desire 2.2, Huawei Ideos 2.2.
But it doesn't run on SGS 2.2.1.

Checking the number of methods of `net.android.wifi.WifiConfiguration`, I see that the regular class (as it comes on Nexus One, Desire, etc.) has 37 methods, while the SGS version has 57. (The WifiConfiguration class is the class where the methods are being invoked.)

So obviously Samsung changed this class, and I'd assume they'd be part of their published open source under http://opensource.samsung.com, but having downloaded GT-I9000_Kernel.tar.gz and GT-I9000_Platform.tar.gz, I don't find any related Wifi related classes, except the lower level wireless drivers in the kernel.
I made a fulltext search through all files regarding wifi, etc.

Some methods that are part of the WifiConfiguration class on SGS, which are not on the regular distribution:

```
checkWpsInProgress
createMulticastLock
getCurrentTime
getProgressLapseTime
getProgressMode
getProgressPinNumber
showApDialog
...
```

and some more.

Anybody working closely with Samsung devices who has a clue? Where to find the complete modifications done by Samsung?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, those modifications have not been published. Since that class was licensed under the Apache 2 license, Samsung is under no obligation to distribute source code.